# How to properly implement View Controller Containers?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I've already implemented a lot of view controller containers but getting the lifecycle completely right is still tricky.

The general approach for adding a child view controller seems simple:

1. Call `parent.addChildViewController(child)` (once!)
2. Call `child.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: …)` (probably multiple times, alternating between `true` and `false`)
3. Add the child's `view` to the parent's view hierarchy
4. Lay out the child's `view`
5. Call `child.endAppearanceTransition()` (once!)
6. Call `child.didMoveToParentViewController(parent)` (once!)

Now it's rarely that simple. For example the parent view controller itself might be in a transition (`viewWillAppear()`) so the steps 5 and 6 must be delayed until the parent also completed it's transition (`viewDidAppear()`).

Situations can be even more complex. And you could accidentally forget to call something. Or a child forgets to call `super.…()`. Or you call a method multiple times which you should not call again (yet).

To find bugs like this I swizzled all the lifecycle methods in `UIViewController` in a library of mine, so that it reports plenty different lifecycle bugs automatically in the log. This works like a charm and I found several issues in my own containers. But I also got several reports from UIKit's own view controllers so now I'm questioning whether I really understand the exact expected lifecycle.

The documentation for `UIViewController.didMoveToParentViewController()` for example reads:

> If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must
>   call the `didMoveToParentViewController:` method of the child view
>   controller after the transition to the new controller is complete or,
>   if there is no transition, immediately after calling the
>   `addChildViewController:` method.

**So now the most important question for me is:**

Are the methods `willMoveToParentViewController()` and `didMoveToParentViewController()` directly related to `view(Did|Will)(Appear|Disappear)`?
I.e. as the documentation excerpt above states I must not call `didMoveToParentViewController()` until the child view controller's transition is completed. That means `viewDidDisappear()` or `viewDidAppear()` must have been called last - neither `viewWillAppear()` nor `viewWillDisappear()`.

UIKit seems to do exactly that (calling `(will|did)MoveToParentViewController` during a transition), for example when presenting a `UISplitViewController` having `UINavigationController` as children modally on an iPhone:

```
VIEW CONTROLLER LIFECYCLE BROKEN for <UINavigationController: 0x7cc18a00>

Problem:
    .willMoveToParentViewController() was called unexpectedly during an appearance transition. It must only be called while the view controller is in DidDisappear or DidAppear state.

Possible Causes:
    - the view controller containment implementation of UISplitViewController or one if its parents is broken



VIEW CONTROLLER LIFECYCLE BROKEN for <UINavigationController: 0x7cc18a00>

Problem:
    .didMoveToParentViewController() was called unexpectedly during an appearance transition. It must only be called while the view controller is in DidDisappear or DidAppear state.

Possible Causes:
    - the view controller containment implementation of the parent view controller or one if its parents is broken
```

The bugs pile up when presenting a `UIAlertViewController` which has a text field:

```
VIEW CONTROLLER LIFECYCLE BROKEN for <_UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewController: 0x7dd84bb0>

Problem:
    .willMoveToParentViewController() was called unexpectedly while view controller is in WillMoveToParent state.

Possible Causes:
    - _UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewController or one of its superclasses called super.willMoveToParentViewController() multiple times
    - _UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewController or one of its superclasses called super.willMoveToParentViewController() from within it's .didMoveToParentViewController()
    - the view controller containment implementation of UIAlertController or one if its parents is broken
    - it was already called implicitly by parent.addChildViewController(_UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewController) so you must not call it again



VIEW CONTROLLER LIFECYCLE BROKEN for <UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7a99fdb0>

Problem:
    .didMoveToParentViewController(non-nil) was not called after .viewDidAppear() to complete an earlier .willMoveToParentViewController(non-nil).

Possible Causes:
    - the view controller containment implementation of UIInputWindowController is likely broken



VIEW CONTROLLER LIFECYCLE BROKEN for <UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7dd67650>

Problem:
    .didMoveToParentViewController(non-nil) was not called after .viewDidAppear() to complete an earlier .willMoveToParentViewController(non-nil).

Possible Causes:
    - the view controller containment implementation of UICompatibilityInputViewController is likely broken
```

**Does anybody have very good insight in how view controller containment is supposed to be done?**
Are these just bugs in UIKit or is this behavior "acceptable"?

In case someone is interested in how the lifecycle validation & bug reporting works have a look at [this file](https://github.com/fluidsonic/JetPack/blob/5b47bd93be920377678c9fac3ae027ef251c6f84/Sources/extensions/UIKit/UIViewController.swift#L343).

Comment: Your entire premise seems flawed. For example, you should not be calling `child.beginAppearanceTransition` at all unless you _also_ have turned off `shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods`.

Comment: You're right, and in my case I also either don't call them or have `shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods` return `false`. It doesn't solve my issues though.

Comment: Well, then I'm not clear on what you're asking. The UIKit behaviors are full of view controller event incoherencies. For example, sometimes `didMoveToParentViewController:` arrives without a corresponding `willMoveToParentViewController:`; and sometimes `didMoveToParentViewController:` arrives even though this view controller was previously the child of this parent and remains the child of this parent (i.e. nothing happened, so why is there any event at all?). If you have more, send them in a bug report, but my experience is that Apple will push them right back at you.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question. Implementing custom containers is very tricky. Things like classic `UISplitViewController` are just buggy, you get `didMove(toParent:)` twice with them so better be avoided.

What I learnt over the years is that `shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods` does not really work well so it's better be turned off:

```swift
override var shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods: Bool {
    return false
}
```

Then you have to forward appearance events manually by implementing appearance related methods in your container and using `beginAppearanceTransition` and `endAppearanceTransition` to instruct UIKit to call the corresponding `view(Will|Did)(Appear|Disappear)` methods:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    children.forEach { vc in
        vc.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: animated)
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    children.forEach { vc in
        vc.endAppearanceTransition()
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    children.forEach { vc in
        vc.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: animated)
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    children.forEach { vc in
        vc.endAppearanceTransition()
    }
}
```

Then when adding children dynamically, I prefer to avoid generating appearance events if container is detached from view hierarchy. Instead container will do that once it itself appears, i.e:

```swift
func addChildController(_ vc: UIViewController) {
    let shouldHandleAppearanceEvents = view.window != nil

    addChild(vc)

    if shouldHandleAppearanceEvents {
        vc.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
    }

    view.addSubview(vc.view)

    if shouldHandleAppearanceEvents {
        vc.endAppearanceTransition()
    }

    vc.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

It's also worth to note that calling `didMove(toParent:)` before `endAppearanceTransition()` may result in `didMove(toParent:)` being called twice so the order here is important.

In more complex containers where children are added with animation, you may need to keep track of children that are in transition, either appearing or disappearing so that hiding your container does not trigger appearance events twice.